# Auto filter with the Array data VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have a sub routine which stores the unique values in a array and based on this array i want to filter the values, below is the Unique values code

```
Sub FUniques()
Range(Range("G2"), Range("G2").End(xlDown)).Select

If Not Selection Is Nothing Then
    For Each cell In Selection
        If (cell <> "") And (InStr(tmp, cell) = 0) Then
             tmp = tmp & cell & "|"
        End If
    Next cell
End If

If Len(tmp) > 0 Then tmp = Left(tmp, Len(tmp) - 1)

arr = Split(tmp, "|")
Cells(1, 1).Select
End Sub
```

Now the above filled arr i want to filter data present in another sheet(sheet1), i'm using the below code,

```
ActiveSheet.Range("$A:$AK").AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:= _
    Join(arr, ", "), Operator:=xlFilterValues
```

Please help me out in this

Comment: Criteria1 is expecting an array,  not a delimited string

Answer (score 0):

Got it rather then using join we should use the direct "arr"

Comment: `Join()` returns a `String` and you want to pass an array that's why it wouldn't work ;)